# How to retrieve news that contains specific keywords using Newsapi?

Tags: javascript, android, json, api, android-studio

I am using android studio.

I want to retrieve news that contains specific keywords in the headlines. I am not using a search bar and I want news to be displayed only according to the keywords specified. I've tried to make changes in my code with respect to the API but my app seems to crash every time . (Btw the can show top headline news just fine. I just cant figure out how to obtain news with particular keywords)

You can refer to the documentation here : [Documentation regarding NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines)

The code related to the API client is provided below:

Newspage :

```
package com.example.nvirone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.nvirone.API.ApiClient;
import com.example.nvirone.API.ApiInterface;
import com.example.nvirone.Models.Article;
import com.example.nvirone.Models.News;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Newspage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String API_KEY = "*unique API KEY*";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private String TAG = Newspage.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newspage);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new Adapter(articles, Newspage.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        LoadJson();
    }
public void LoadJson(){
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String country = Utils.getCountry();

    Call<News> call;
    call = apiInterface.getNews(country,"environment", API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
            List<Article> newArticles = response.body().getArticle();
            if (response.isSuccessful() && newArticles!=null){
                adapter.addArticles(newArticles);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Newspage.this,"NO result",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

API interface:

```
package com.example.nvirone.API;

import com.example.nvirone.Models.News;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("everything")
    Call<News> getNews(

            @Query("country") String country,
            @Query("q") String keyword,
            @Query("apiKey") String apiKey
    );
}
```